# PHP if only 1 character - Get All Days In a Year

Tags: php, date, strlen

I am trying to see if a var is only 1 character and if so I will add a 0 before it.

I would think `if(strlen($a)==1)` but it does not. Below is my full code.

In short what I am trying to do is get **all of the days of the year** and put any given year in an array in this format.

Month Day Year like this `010115` that would be `January 1st 2015`. Then i would like to put the whole year in an array; All 365 days in any given year. Hard coded it would look like this

```
$AllDaysIn2015= array(010115, 010215, 010315, 010415, 010515, etc... );
```

But how would I get all of them into one array in this format?

To achieve this I am starting here but got stuck on counting the 1 character.

```
function daysInMonth($year)
{
    for($i = 1; $i < 12; $i++)
    {
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $year); // 31
    echo $num . "<br>";
        for($a =1; $a < $num+1; $a++)
        {
            $a = trim($a);
            if(strlen($a)==1)
            {
            $a = "0$a";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "$a, ";
            }


        }
    echo "<br>";
    }
}

daysInMonth(2014);
```

Comment: Why do you want them in an array like that?

Comment: Because later I am going to call a script and goes by a give date. Then the code will save content based off of the DAY sent to it. I need the full date, Month, Day and Year to send to this script and I need to do it 365 times, once for each day.

Comment: the logic is fine, but you only echo for greater than 2digits (with a comma) or assign for less than. you should be doing one or other for all - really `rerun $a; `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Un</s>[tested](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rfRwWi):

```
<?php
function daysInMonth($year) {
    $dates = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $year); 
        for($a = 1; $a < $num+1; $a++) {
            $dates[] = sprintf('%02d%02d%04d', $i, $a, $year);
        }
    }
    return $dates;
}

$datesInYear = daysInMonth(2014);
```

This uses `sprintf()` to handle the formatting for you. No need to check the length of the number.

Comment: Thanks @dagon. Looks like I need to change `$i < 12` to `$i <= 12`

Comment: Amazing, it works. How would I get only 14 rather than 2014 at the end... or 15 rather than 2015. But thank you so much for the help so far.

Comment: Just use substr() to get the last two digits from the year.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

```
$a = str_pad($a, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Comment: but how would I do a IF statement with that. Because only 1 thru 9 each month would be 1 char. I don't need a 0 before all of them.

Comment: That will only pad it if there is 1 character. It will ensure that the length is 2.

Comment: remember to include the last parameter as `str_pad` defaults to adding the '0's to the right side of the text you pass.

Comment: Whoops missed that. Edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Hammered out some quick code, but jmeyer2k beat me to it. I figured I'd post what I'd written as it's a little more complete and gives some context

```
function days_in_month($year){
    $data = array();

    for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
        $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $year);
        for($a=1; $a<=$num; $a++){
            $a = str_pad($a,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $data[] = str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).$a.$year;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I haven't tested it, so it may be a little buggy (currently working from a different machine than regular)